# Creating Excel reports with Hyperlinks to other Excel worksheets via SSRS 2016

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I need to create excel reports with SSRS 2016. These reports have need to have a `sheet 1` that is an index to the other sheets. I can get the excel function inserted correctly using an expression. The expression is as follows:

```
="=HYPERLINK(" & chr(34) & "#" & "'" & "Sheet2" & "'" & "!A4" & chr(34) & "," & chr(34) & "TEST" & chr(34) & ")"
```

This creates the correct hyperlink syntax in the excel cell.  This syntax is as follows:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet2'!A4","TEST")
```

The problem is that I have to click the cell once before it will behave as a hyperlink and just show the word TEST. After I click it once it works as desired. However, I need it to render from the start as a hyperlink. Any ideas?

I also tried doing it as just text but as soon as SSRS sees the "=" it interprets it as an expression.

It is almost impossible to find any advanced excel formatting (via SSRS) on the web. Almost all the info is very rudimentary.

Comment: Another tact to consider are [Document Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-document-map-report-builder-and-ssrs)

Comment: Yes Document maps are close to what i needed.  Bookmarks are what I ended up using:
https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/bookmarks-ssrs/